# how to use multiple values in switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, comma-operator

My program is

```
int main() {
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
    switch (i++, j--) {
        case 10:
            printf("The number is 10");
            break;
        case 20:
            printf("The number is 20");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Input Invalid");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and i am getting output `The number is 20`. I need to know how it works can u explain. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator \`,\` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You're using the [**comma operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) here. In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token `,`) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Thus

```
switch (i++, j--) {...}
```

is equivalent to

```
i++;
switch (j--) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the switch case improperly. You are accepting two variable as an argument,

```
switch(a++ , b--)
{
   case(a>b):
   case(b<a):
   case(a==b):
}
```

If you solely give one number and two arguments, the compiler doesn't know what to do with them.

This is my experience if you are using a c based language.